# Laravel send json back in certain format

Tags: php, json, laravel, vue.js

My vue.js application shows json request error messages from my Laravel application. Those error messages are received like this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "description": [
      "The description field is required."
    ],
    "from": [
      "The from field is required."
    ],
    "to": [
      "The to field is required."
    ],
    "kmz": [
      "The kmz field is required."
    ],
    "kmp": [
      "The kmp field is required."
    ],
    "hour": [
      "The hour field is required."
    ],
    "maps": [
      "The maps field is required."
    ]
  }
}
```

So how would I send another message in the same format with Laravel? For example:

```
return response()->json(['error' => 'U kunt maximaal 20 locaties aanmaken.'], 400);
```

Right now with that ^ I see this:

[image]

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added new error message in validator message bag

```
$validator->getMessageBag()->add('error', 'Your message here');
return response()->json(array('error' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()), 400);
```

Pass single message like this

```
$error_message = array('slot-time' =>'Slot end time should be greater than start time');
return response()->json(array('error' => $error_message), 400);
```

Comment: Okay, And how would I do this with the request validator. So `php artisan make:request ValidateRequest` ?

Comment: public function postSignIn(Request $request)
{ 
  $request_data = $request->all();
  $validator = $this->login_rules($request_data);   
  if($validator->fails())
  {
    $validator = $validator->getMessageBag()->add('error', 'Your message here');
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
  }
  else
  {
    //DO THIS    
  } 
}